# CANopenNode: Master node sends continually a message

Tags: stm32, can-bus, canopen

I am trying to use CANopenNode into a STM32L476 device by using libohiboard as HAL library. In the network, I have: (i) my board that operates as a master and (ii) a commercial node. At startup, the node sends HB message and SYNC message. When my board use
`CO_NMT_sendCommand(CO->NMT,CO_NMT_ENTER_OPERATIONAL, 0x0A);`
the master starts to send continually the same message without stopping!

With logic analyzer I see this:
[image]
Where Channel 0 is the TX pins of the microcontroller, and Channel 1 is the RX pin.

I can't understand why the message returns into RX pin immediately! I checked the microcontroller configuration and the loopback mode is OFF.
[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Looks like normal CAN operation - all messages are immediately echoed back while they are sent or else bus arbitration wouldn't work. The only difference is the ACK bit which you can see are set on the rx line but not on tx. This bit is filled in by the other CAN node on the bus.

The reason why your node keeps sending the same message doesn't seem related to this.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how it works on your controller but usually you have to pay attention to send NMT_start_command only when your slave node doesn't return any heartbeat or if the heartbeat value is different than the mode expected (pre operational or operational as an example)

If the slave doesn't return anything there might be multiple reasons:

- nothing activated so you have first to set a time using the right SDO
- the slave use nodeguarding instead of heartbeat so you have to query first the slave with a message ID: 0x700 + Node ID, DLC: 0

Please let me know if it is not clear or doesn't help